# "Voting corrected" seems incomplete

Tags: bug, reputation, serial-voting

A few days ago, I was surprised to see a sudden increase in rep of 80 points in the space of a couple minutes. When looking over my profile today, I saw that I had lost 60 points, with the annotation "Voting corrected (learn more)". I'm not surprised at the loss; I am, however, surprised that it seems to not have removed all 80.

As far as I can tell, the "uncorrected" upvotes seem to be at [Seeing modules as ring extensions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/267686/seeing-modules-as-ring-extensions) and [Invariants for $SO_n \backslash \mathfrak{gl}_n / SO_n$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/348112/invariants-for-so-n-backslash-mathfrakgl-n-so-n). They were the last 2 upvotes, and the only two to happen in the second minute.

Is this a bug/something the "correction" bot missed?

Comment: Are you *really* sure the remaining votes were by the same user as the other ones? This could have been a coincidence if, for example, one of the posts was mentioned somewhere so that it attracted attention.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I have no way to be sure; I can't see who the upvoter was. I can say that I don't think either has had the kind of recent attention necessary; one had its last update 3 years ago and was linked to in another question last year, while the other had its most recent automatic update two months ago. Both were upvoted within about a minute of the others, so it seems very likely to be part of the same spree. Part of why I posted here was to get the attention of someone who might have the privileges to see if it was the same upvoter.